# Hacer un update con una funcion de agregacion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

tengo el siguiente error al querer hacer un update

```
    UPDATE a SET a.Apagar = SUM(b.Importe/100.00)
    FROM #tmp_repspendientesconimporte AS a
    JOIN #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS as b on a.NumeroCheque=b.NumeroCheque
    WHERE
    a.NumeroCheque>0 and b.Importe>0 and b.Concepto not like '%Factura %' and Ajuste=0 and LEN( foliofactura)=36
```

El error es el siguiente:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Entiendo que es por querer asignar la SUM del importe al update, pero no entiendo como arreglarlo, leyendo en internet veo que puede ser con una subconsulta pero no entiendo como aplicarla a mi query

Edit: hice esta consulta

```
UPDATE a SET a.Apagar = (SELECT SUM(b.Importe/100.00) FROM #tmp_repspendientesconimporte AS a
    JOIN #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS as b on a.NumeroCheque=b.NumeroCheque
    WHERE
    a.NumeroCheque>0 and b.Importe>0 and b.Concepto not like '%Factura %' and Ajuste=0 and LEN( foliofactura)=36)
    FROM  #tmp_repspendientesconimporte AS a
```

Pero me realiza el update a todos los registros

Comment: Te faltó indicar en qué motor de BD estás trabajando. Nombre y versión.

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: tu ultima consulta esta bien.. solo le falta el where...

Answer (score 0):

El detalle es que tienes que hacer el agregado antes de usar el JOIN. Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo. Sin embargo, es posible que tenga errores porque hay columnas que no tenían indicado a que tabla pertenecen.

```
UPDATE pci SET 
    Apagar = SUM( pp.Importe / 100.00)
FROM #tmp_repspendientesconimporte          AS pci
JOIN (SELECT NumeroCheque,
            SUM(b.Importe/100.00)
      FROM  #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS 
      WHERE Importe > 0 
      AND   Concepto not like '%Factura %'
      GROUP BY NumeroCheque)                AS pp ON pci.NumeroCheque = pp.NumeroCheque
WHERE pci.NumeroCheque > 0 
AND   pci.Ajuste = 0 
AND   LEN( pci.foliofactura) = 36;
```

No tengas miedo de usar espacio en blanco para hacer más fácil de leer tu código. También acostumbra a darle un alias relevante a las tablas en vez de usar letras en orden alfabético.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero el escenario, para ver como funciona.

```
Create table #tmp_repspendientesconimporte 
    (
    foliofactura uniqueidentifier, 
    Ajuste int,
    NumeroCheque int,
    Apagar float
    );
Create table #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS
    (
    Importe float,
    NumeroCheque int,
    Concepto varchar(100),
    Ajuste int
    );
```

Los tipos de datos, pueden no coincidir, porque no los has definido en la pregunta.

```
Insert into #tmp_repspendientesconimporte
(foliofactura, Ajuste, NumeroCheque, Apagar)
values
(newid(), 1, 100, null),
(newid(), 1, 110, null);

Insert into #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS
(Importe, NumeroCheque, Concepto, Ajuste)
values
(25.5, 100, 'Concepto1', 0),
(15.2, 100, 'Concepto2', 0),
(17.3, 100, 'Concepto3', 0),
(15000, 100, 'Factura',1),
(212.8, 110, 'Concepto1', 0),
(315.4, 110, 'Concepto2', 0),
(417.6, 110, 'Concepto3', 0);
```

Ahora con los datos:

Hacer una subconsulta, no es más que extraer lo que necesitas en una `tabla derivada` y darle un alias, pero muy importante, si quieres acceder a su contenido, las columnas tienen que tener un valor identificativo = **Alias**. Si está utilizando la función Sum(columna) hay que retornarla como Sum(columna) as ....

```
UPDATE a SET a.Apagar = (b.Importe/ 100.0)
    From #tmp_repspendientesconimporte a 
    Inner join 
        (SELECT SUM(b.Importe/100.00) as Importe, NumeroCheque FROM
             #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS as b 
             where b.Concepto not like '%Factura %' and Ajuste=0
                and b.Importe > 0
        Group by NumeroCheque
        ) as b on a.NumeroCheque = b.NumeroCheque

    WHERE
    a.NumeroCheque>0 and  LEN(a.foliofactura)=36;
```

Por tanto en la tabla de alias a, cuando se asigna un valor, es un valor escalar. En este caso, el proveniente de la tabla de alias b, y ya lo tratas como un valor.

**Otra opción** es el uso del operador `apply`.

```
UPDATE a SET a.Apagar = (c.Importe/100.0)
    From #tmp_repspendientesconimporte a 
    cross apply
        (SELECT SUM(b.Importe/100.00) as Importe, NumeroCheque FROM
             #tmp_chepagosproveedoresREPS as b 
             where b.Concepto not like '%Factura %' and Ajuste=0
                and b.Importe > 0
                and a.NumeroCheque = b.NumeroCheque
        Group by NumeroCheque
        ) as c 

    WHERE
    a.NumeroCheque>0 and   LEN(a.foliofactura)=36;
```

Aquí la diferencia radica en que es en la parte interior del subconjunto `c` donde se igualan ambos `and a.NumeroCheque = b.NumeroCheque`.

[image: Resultado]